# Corrplot with a lot of variables

Tags: r

how could I remedy a corrplot with lots of variables. Because visually it's not appealing.
Below is my code:

```
corrplot(cor(dataT[,c("D_Wavg_EASI_DENSITY_CWR_2", "D_Wavg_EASI_POP16_CWR_2", 
                                "D_Wavg_EASI_URBANPOP_P_CWR_2", "D_Wavg_EASI_RURALPOP_P_CWR_2",
                                "D_Wavg_EASI_MEDHHINC_CWR_2", "D_Wavg_EASI_ED_C_P_CWR_2",
                                "D_Wavg_EASI_WHCOLROCC_P_CWR_2", "D_Wavg_EASI_BLCOLROCC_P_CWR_2",
                                "D_Wavg_EASI_CARTHEFT_CWR_2", "D_Wavg_EASI_TOTCRIME_CWR_2",
                                "D_Wavg_EASI_MAXTEMP_CWR_2", "D_Wavg_EASI_MINTEMP_CWR_2",
                                "D_Wavg_EASI_RAINDAYS_CWR_2", "D_Wavg_EASI_SNOWDAYS_CWR_2",
                                "D_Wavg_EASI_ANNULRAIN_CWR_2", "D_Wavg_EASI_ANNULSNOW_CWR_2",
                                "D_Wavg_EASI_EASIWETHI_CWR_2", "D_Wavg_EASI_MED_INC_CWR_2",
                                "D_Wavg_EASI_PROPCRIME_CWR_2","D_Wavg_EASI_LARCENY_CWR_2",
                                "D_Wavg_EASI_BURGLARY_CWR_2","D_Wavg_EASI_ROBBERY_CWR_2")]))
```

And this is what the output looks like. The names of the variables overlap each other
[image]

Comment: Give the variables shorter more meaningful labels.

Comment: Or use an interactive solution where you show the names only when highlighted https://plot.ly/r/heatmaps/

Comment: Using `ggplot2`, you can resize the labels (and other stuff) and mix it with the above suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from what has been suggested already, there is another quite simple solution.
Assuming you have data like this:

```
cars <- cor(mtcars)
```

you can shrink the size of the text labels by adding the argument `tl.cex`and defining a value < 1, like here:

```
corrplot(cars, tl.cex=0.5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a LOT of variables (e.g. 100) such that reading the individual row names is not feasible, one approach could be to label them with common groupings if that exists in your data. For me this has been useful for illustrating brain networks, where I have hundreds of brain regions but I would like to illustrate them as grouped by their network.

The key to this is to pipe your plot into the corrRect() function to draw rectangles on your plot.
Also in your corrplot() function remove the messy rownames with: tl.pos = 'n'

```
cars <- cor(mtcars) #Get correlation matrix
rownames(cars) #List the rownames so you can choose where you would like to see the boundaries

r_horiz <- rbind( c('mpg', 'mpg', 'hp', 'carb'), #insert names as "Top left corner 1", "Top left corner coord 2", "bottom right corner coord 1", "bottom right coord 2"
                c('mpg', 'mpg', 'qsec', "carb" ),
                c('mpg', 'mpg', "carb",'carb' )) #State where you want the corners of your horizontal rectangles

r_vert <- rbind( c('mpg', 'mpg',  'carb', 'hp'), #to go from horizontal to vertical (for symmetrical matrices) flip the order of the 3rd and 4th names
            c('mpg', 'mpg', "carb",'qsec' ),
            c('mpg', 'mpg', "carb",'carb' )) #State where you want the corners of your vertical rectangles

Lab2 <- rbind( c('mpg', 'mpg',  'wt', 'carb'),
               c('mpg', 'mpg', "carb",'wt' ),
               c('mpg', 'mpg', "carb",'carb' )) #You can include multiple batches of rectangles and use colour to convey their different meanings

plot_cor <-  corrplot(as.matrix(cars),  method = "color",
             col = col(100), col.lim=c(-1,1), tl.pos = 'n', #HERE, tl.pos = 'n' removes individual row labels. If you have few enough you can use tl.cex = 0.4 instead to include them but smaller 
             title = "This is my corplot", mar=c(0,0,1,0),  diag = T) %>% corrRect(namesMat = r_horiz)  %>% corrRect(namesMat = r_vert) %>% corrRect(namesMat =  Lab2,  col = "red")
```

[image: Example corrplot with groupings illustrated with lines]

To add labels of the groups you can change your row and column names to empty ("") for all but the middle row and choose what you want to name the group, or you can label them after the fact with annotation. If you find these methods too clunky perhaps you should use ggplot instead of corrplot. The basic would be from an uncorrelated matrix

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x=V1, y=V2, fill=value))
```

and you could add lines and annotations with

```
+ geom_hline(yintercept = 5) + geom_vline(xintercept = 10) +
 annotate("text", x = 5, y = 5, label = "Group1")
```